# SignalR references NuGet package(s) that are missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, signalr, chat

I'm trying to use **SignalR** with this tutorial:

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

but on the stage of debugging I got this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. The
>   missing file is
>   ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.    SignalRChat C:\test\SignalRChat\SignalRChat.csproj  103

Not sure what I have to install and where to download it. So I've installed:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR,
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core,
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS,
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb

first time I have deal with SignalR I did this just strictly according to instructions, so need to figure out

So if I jump through the error, it shows me form, it does not opens localhost to enter user name, opens directly http://localhost:61202/index.html and when I write text and push send message I can't see it display below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error says you have a missing signalR package. Try to enable Nuget Package Restore on your solution. There are a few ways of doing this.

- Right click on your solution **->** Click Enable NuGet Package Restore. Nuget will try to update your missing packages on build

OR

- Using your Nuget Package Manager by going to Tools **->** Package Manager Console. Then type in Update-Package **name of the package**

OR

- right click your solution, then click Manage Nuget Packages. Under Installed packages, you can search for SignalR just to see if it is really installed.

IF SignalR is already installed, then check to see if it is referenced in your project.

Hope this helps.